# why javascript Form Processing is no standard at all ？

Tags: javascript

After my test,

The first way to write

```
<form name="form" >   
        <input type="text" id="tx1" value="123"><br>
    </form>
<script>
    alert(form.tx1.value);   

</script>
```

The second way to write

```
<form id="form" >   
        <input type="text" id="tx1" value="123"><br>
    </form>
<script>
    alert(form.tx1.value);   

</script>
```

The third way to write

```
<form id="form" >  
        <input type="text" id="tx1" value="123"><br>
    </form>
<script>
    alert(form.elements['tx1'].value);     

</script>
```

The forth way to write

```
<form id="form" >  
        <input type="text" name="tx1" value="123"><br>
    </form>
<script>
    alert(form.elements['tx1'].value);     

</script>
```

........
Permutations and combinations are many, pay attention to the form's id, name and input the id, the name, combined with the wording of the js, no matter how you write, are no problem. .
There is no standard at all. . . .

Comment: The last two examples are not different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there *is* a standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-40002357

On top of the standard, most browsers implement additional features.

The safest way to refer to form elements through a named collection is:

```
<form name="formname">
    <input type="text" name="tx1" value="123">
</form>
<script>
alert(document.forms['formname'].elements['tx1'].value);     
</script>
```

[`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.forms) is a `HTMLCollection` of `<form>` elements. In each of these form, the `elements` property is a collection of all form input elements. All elements have to be referred **by `name`**.

Comment: I must add: if there are **multiple** elements with the **same name** in the **same form**, then `elements` will be a `NodeList` object. Each element can then be referred through numeric indexes, in the order of occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
<form id="form" >   
    <input type="text" id="tx1" value="123"><br/>
</form>
<script>
    alert(tx1.value);   
</script>
```